# How to remove files from a folder owned by someone else

Tags: linux, permissions

I can't find the solution to a problem under unix that look really simple, I have a folder `folder` owned by `root`.

I have a user `www-data` who is able to write and read files in this folder. I also have a user `prod` that should be able to remove files from `folder`.

In order to solve that, `www-data` and `prod` both have acl rights on `folder` for read and write operations.

The problem is that `prod` is unable to remove the files, `root` can however.

How should I solve that issue without sudo ?

I'm pretty sure this question has been asked already, but I can't find it anywhere

Comment: You can't.  You can either log into the root user and delete the files or log into the root user and change the owner fo those files then delete the files with that user/group

Comment: have you considered using SetGID on the parent directory, and setting the parent's owner group to be a group that both users are in, and finally providing delete rights to the group? you will initially have to set ownership on the directory's contents recursively to root:youWebGroup and the permissions to 77x.

Comment: @Ramhound I wanted a kind of restricted root, because a script log as `prod` and needs to be able to do whatever `root` can do, but only within the folder `folder`.

Comment: @FrankThomas I don't have a hand on the files permissions and I wanted to avoid to log as `root`, I wanted to configure the user `prod` to be a kind of master of the `folder` folder

Comment: you would not have to log in as root at all, once you have modified the dir ownership and permissions initially. you would login as a member of yourWebGroup, which would include both www-data and prod. so you login as prod, and can modify/delete files, and thanks to setGID, all new files would absorb the parents ownergroup to keep everything working after it has been set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something related to the acl.

I just set the default permissions for the directory `folder` to `prod` so every files `www-data` will create will also belong to `prod` thanks to acl :

`setfacl -Rm d:u:prod:rwx folder`

Answer (score 0):

set umask 0000 for user www-data

Then all the files it writes will be 666 and anyone, including your prod user can read/write/delete them

Another way of doing it is to alter the uid of the "prod" user to be the same as the www-data user.  This may have other odd effects but it could achieve what you state you want to do!

Comment: Seems a good solution, but isn't it unsafe to do so ?